# Tomcat 8 throwing - org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource

Tags: caching, resources, tomcat8

I have just upgraded Tomcat from version 7.0.52 to 8.0.14.

I am getting this for lots of static image files:

> **org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource** Unable to add the
>   resource at [/base/1325/WA6144-150x112.jpg] to the cache because there
>   was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache
>   entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache

I haven't specified any particular resource settings, and I didn't get this for 7.0.52.

I have found mention of this happening at startup in a bug report that was supposedly fixed.  For me this is happening not at startup but constantly when the resource is requested.

Anybody else having this issue?

Trying to at least just disable the cache, but I cannot find an example of how to specify not to use the cache.  The attributes have gone from the context in Tomcat version 8. Have tried adding a resource but cannot get the config right.

```xml
<Resource name="file" 
    cachingAllowed="false"
    className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.FileResourceSet"
/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: No replies - I guess I must be the only person with this issue.

Comment: Solution is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/644415/tomcat-8-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource

Comment: Regarding the missing attribute in Tomcat 8 context, here is an excerpt from the migration guide (emphasis mine): "_The refactoring of resources has also resulted in a **number of attributes being removed from the default Context implementation** (org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext). The following attributes **may now be configured via the resources implementation** used by the web application_". More info in the related [migration guid](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Web_application_resources).

Comment: @iainmac999 having never selected a correct answer after 2 years we can agree it works both ways?

Answer (score 244):

I had the same issue when upgrading from Tomcat 7 to 8: a continuous large flood of log warnings about cache.

## 1. Short Answer

Add this within the [`Context`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Attributes) xml element of your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`:

```xml
<!-- The default value is 10240 kbytes, even when not added to context.xml.
So increase it high enough, until the problem disappears, for example set it to 
a value 5 times as high: 51200. -->
<Resources cacheMaxSize="51200" />
```

So the default is `10240` (10 mbyte), so set a size higher than this. Than tune for optimum settings where the warnings disappear.
Note that the warnings may come back under higher traffic situations.

### 1.1 The cause (short explanation)

The problem is caused by Tomcat being unable to reach its target cache size due to cache entries that are less than the TTL of those entries. So Tomcat didn't have enough cache entries that it could expire, because they were too fresh, so it couldn't free enough cache and thus outputs warnings.

The problem didn't appear in Tomcat 7 because Tomcat 7 simply didn't output warnings in this situation. (Causing you and me to use poor cache settings without being notified.)

The problem appears when receiving a relative large amount of HTTP requests for resources (usually static) in a relative short time period compared to the size and TTL of the cache. If the cache is reaching its maximum (10mb by default) with more than 95% of its size with fresh cache entries (fresh means less than less than 5 seconds in cache), than you will get a warning message for each webResource that Tomcat tries to load in the cache.

### 1.2 Optional info

Use JMX if you need to tune cacheMaxSize on a running server without rebooting it.

The quickest fix would be to completely disable cache: `<Resources cachingAllowed="false" />`, but that's suboptimal, so increase cacheMaxSize as I just described.

## 2. Long Answer

### 2.1 Background information

A [WebSource](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.24/org/apache/catalina/WebResource.java) is a file or directory in a web application. For performance reasons, Tomcat can cache WebSources. The [maximum of the static resource cache](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html#Common_Attributes) (all resources in total) is by default 10240 kbyte (10 mbyte). A webResource is loaded into the cache when the webResource is requested (for example when loading a static image), it's then called a cache entry.
Every cache entry has a [TTL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html#Common_Attributes) (time to live), which is the time that the cache entry is allowed to stay in the cache. When the TTL expires, the cache entry is eligible to be removed from the cache. The default value of the cacheTTL is 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).

There is more to tell about caching, but that is irrelevant for the problem.

### 2.2 The cause

The following code from the [Cache class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.24/org/apache/catalina/webresources/Cache.java) shows the caching policy in detail:

```
152  // Content will not be cached but we still need metadata size
153  long delta = cacheEntry.getSize();
154  size.addAndGet(delta);
156  if (size.get() > maxSize) {
157      // Process resources unordered for speed. Trades cache
158      // efficiency (younger entries may be evicted before older
159      // ones) for speed since this is on the critical path for
160      // request processing
161      long targetSize =
162              maxSize * (100 - TARGET_FREE_PERCENT_GET) / 100;
163      long newSize = evict(
164              targetSize, resourceCache.values().iterator());
165      if (newSize > maxSize) {
166          // Unable to create sufficient space for this resource
167          // Remove it from the cache
168          removeCacheEntry(path);
169          log.warn(sm.getString("cache.addFail", path));
170      }
171  }
```

When loading a webResource, the code calculates the new size of the cache. If the calculated size is larger than the default maximum size, than one or more cached entries have to be removed, otherwise the new size will exceed the maximum. So the code will calculate a "targetSize", which is the size the cache wants to stay under (as an optimum), which is by default 95% of the maximum. In order to reach this targetSize, entries have to be removed/evicted from the cache. This is done using the following code:

```
215  private long evict(long targetSize, Iterator<CachedResource> iter) {
217      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
219      long newSize = size.get();
221      while (newSize > targetSize && iter.hasNext()) {
222          CachedResource resource = iter.next();
224          // Don't expire anything that has been checked within the TTL
225          if (resource.getNextCheck() > now) {
226              continue;
227          }
229          // Remove the entry from the cache
230          removeCacheEntry(resource.getWebappPath());
232          newSize = size.get();
233      }
235      return newSize;
236  }
```

So a cache entry is removed when its TTL is expired and the targetSize hasn't been reached yet.

After the attempt to free cache by evicting cache entries, the code will do:

```
165  if (newSize > maxSize) {
166      // Unable to create sufficient space for this resource
167      // Remove it from the cache
168      removeCacheEntry(path);
169      log.warn(sm.getString("cache.addFail", path));
170  }
```

So if after the attempt to free cache, the size still exceeds the maximum, it will show the warning message about being unable to free:

```
cache.addFail=Unable to add the resource at [{0}] to the cache for web application [{1}] because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
```

### 2.3 The problem

So as the warning message says, the problem is

> insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache

If your web application loads a lot of uncached webResources (about maximum of cache, by default 10mb) within a short time (5 seconds), then you'll get the warning.

The confusing part is that Tomcat 7 didn't show the warning. This is simply caused by this Tomcat 7 code:

```
1606  // Add new entry to cache
1607  synchronized (cache) {
1608      // Check cache size, and remove elements if too big
1609      if ((cache.lookup(name) == null) && cache.allocate(entry.size)) {
1610          cache.load(entry);
1611      }
1612  }
```

combined with:

```
231  while (toFree > 0) {
232      if (attempts == maxAllocateIterations) {
233          // Give up, no changes are made to the current cache
234          return false;
235      }
```

So Tomcat 7 simply doesn't output any warning at all when it's unable to free cache, whereas Tomcat 8 will output a warning.

So if you are using Tomcat 8 with the same default caching configuration as Tomcat 7, and you got warnings in Tomcat 8, than your (and mine) caching settings of Tomcat 7 were performing poorly without warning.

### 2.4 Solutions

There are multiple solutions:

1. Increase cache (recommended)
2. Lower the TTL (not recommended)
3. Suppress cache log warnings (not recommended)
4. Disable cache

#### 2.4.1. Increase cache (recommended)

As described here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html

By adding `<Resources cacheMaxSize="XXXXX" />` within the `Context` element in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`, where "XXXXX" stands for an increased cache size, specified in kbytes. The default is 10240 (10 mbyte), so set a size higher than this.

You'll have to tune for optimum settings. Note that the problem may come back when you suddenly have an increase in traffic/resource requests.

To avoid having to restart the server every time you want to try a new cache size, you can change it without restarting by using JMX.

To [enable JMX](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JMX_Remote_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener), add this to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` within the `Server` element:
`<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" rmiRegistryPortPlatform="6767" rmiServerPortPlatform="6768" />` and download  `catalina-jmx-remote.jar` from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi and put it in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. 
Then use jConsole (shipped by default with the Java JDK) to connect over JMX to the server and look through the settings for settings to increase the cache size while the server is running. Changes in these settings should take affect immediately.

#### 2.4.2. Lower the TTL (not recommended)

Lower the `cacheTtl` value by something lower than 5000 milliseconds and tune for optimal settings.

For example: `<Resources cacheTtl="2000" />`

This comes effectively down to having and filling a cache in ram without using it.

#### 2.4.3. Suppress cache log warnings (not recommended)

Configure logging to disable the logger for `org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache`.

For more info about logging in Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html

#### 2.4.4. Disable cache

You can disable the cache by setting [`cachingAllowed`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html) to `false`.
`<Resources cachingAllowed="false" />`

Although I can remember that in a beta version of Tomcat 8, I was using JMX to disable the cache. (Not sure why exactly, but there may be a problem with disabling the cache via server.xml.)

Comment: Increase cache ? I doubt it would work...
I saw this:
private long maxSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
in the source.
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.12/org/apache/catalina/webresources/Cache.java

Comment: did you found the answer to why tomcat8 is flooding cache warnnings

Comment: @HoaPhan 10*1024*1024 is a maximum of 10mb for all cache in total. Depending on the traffic of the webapp, this can be reached within seconds. Increasing it far enough, will work.

Comment: @PHPAvenger Tomcat 7 didn't warn at all in this sitation, whereas Tomcat 8 does, so it can be seen as a warning feature. The problem is that it warns not just once, but on every to-cache resource request. It would be an improvement to only warn after a certain amount of time or cache target hits.

Comment: @Devabc flawless answer! An SO classic!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143525/jar-getting-inflated-when-any-class-is-referred-for-first-time-hence-large-del is this the same issue, mentioned in this ticket ?

Comment: I am facing this kind of issue, loading lib files again and again on every HTTP request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347100/java-util-jar-jarfile-init-method-takes-too-long-to-execute can you help me in this !

Comment: Any way i can check in the heap on what is there in the cache and how much?? we have increased the cache to 150M, we still get the error.

Comment: Overall excellent explanation, but 2.4.2 is clearly setting the wrong parameter.

Comment: Thanks!
One more side comment: if one sets cacheMaxSize="0" with the intent of disabling caching you'll get a different warning that cacheMaxObjectSize had to be adapted to 0 to match.

Comment: On Ubuntu, the location context.xml is `/etc/tomcat9/context.xml`. You might have to adjust the version number for Tomcat in the path.

Answer (score 169):

In your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` add block below before `</Context>`

```
<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />
```

For more information: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html

Comment: Individual readers will likely want to adjust that cacheMaxSize value to something less than 100 megs.

Comment: so far the error message was flooding my console logs. Now its clear. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You have more static resources that the cache has room for. You can do one of the following:

- Increase the size of the cache
- Decrease the TTL for the cache
- Disable caching

For more details see the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html) for these configuration options.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I do understand the meaning of the exception, and of course I did read the documentation that you linked to, however I do not understand why this would change from 7 to 8 with no configuration changes.  That is, why would the default File System Resource handler be different in 8 to 7, without reference to any change, and it's suspicious that a start up bug was reported and supposedly fixed.

Comment: Perhaps if you had read the migration guide - specifically http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Web_application_resources - things would be clearer.

Comment: It would help if the documentation did a bit more to a) explain what resources go into this cache and why (a lot of misunderstandings abound about that!) and b) what impact different settings can have (e.g. just blindly making each webapp's cache setting quite large can eat a ton of memory) and how to tune this properly.
It would also help if there were a distinction in code and configuration between caching static resources used by the application itself vs. static files requested by user agents and merely delivered by the application.

Answer (score 7):

This isn’t a solution in the sense that it doesn’t resolve the conditions which cause the message to appear in the logs, but the message can be suppressed by appending the following to `conf/logging.properties`:

```
org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.level = SEVERE
```

This filters out the “Unable to add the resource” logs, which are at level WARNING.

In my view a `WARNING` is not necessarily an error that needs to be addressed, but rather can be ignored if desired.

Comment: Haha. this does not solve the problem. It just doesn't show it. WTF!

Comment: This solves the issue of excessive logging, which can be a significant problem on its own. It returns to the behavior of prior tomcat versions, where things worked sufficiently well for many, so in that sense it "solves" the problem. It does not address the problem of actually tuning the tomcat cache, which the answer by devabc covers very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Some more tip (issue i meet):
if $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml ovverrides by intellij.

Just add inside block `<Context> </Context>`:

`<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />`

in your Tomcat/apache-tomcat-x.x.x/conf/context.xml