# Unable to eliminate Tomcat Cache warnings in catalina.out

Tags: tomcat8, catalina.out

Since switching to Tomcat 8, I continually get messages like this in my catalina.out

org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [/intranet/includes/MailFunctions.jsp] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache

I've found in the docs to add entries like cachingAllowed="false" antiResourceLocking="false" antiJARLocking="true" cacheMaxSize="0" cacheTTL="1" to my META-INF/context.xml file which I've done, but this doesn't seem to eliminate the problem.

Does anyone know how to stop these messages?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 8 throwing - org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893297/tomcat-8-throwing-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource-unable-to)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For anyone else unable to find an answer to this problem, the answer seems
to be as simple as adding this to your $SERVER_HOME/conf/context.xml
inside the  tag

Comment: What is to be added?

Comment: There is no code here? 'adding this' doesn't say what to add

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but found an answer in another post which worked for me

In your $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml add the  block below before

```
</Context>

<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />
```

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

“inside the tag ” in where, I think ：

1. Tomcat/bin/catalina.bat  int this  add `set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true [-XX:MaxPermSize=128M]`
2. eclipse->windows->preferences..->tomcat->jvm..->jvm  add `-Xms256m -Xmx512m`
3. eclipse->preference->Java->instal jres->edit add `-Xms256M -Xmx640M -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still looking for a solution. This line should be added inside the Context tag

```
<Context ...>
...
<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />
</Context>
```