# spring-boot how to find the optimal context-cache size for static content?

Tags: tomcat, caching, spring-boot

Using tomcat8 (embedded), 
each-time it can't free some cache to serve static content.
spring-boot warns (screams):

> The background cache eviction process was unable to free [10] percent
>   of the cache for Context [] - consider increasing the maximum size of
>   the cache. After eviction approximately [9,723] KB of data remained in
>   the cache.

Luckily, it is possible to increase tomcat's cache by accessing `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` by [one method](http://howcanfix.com/44879/how-does-spring-boot-control-tomcat-cache) or [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146476/how-does-spring-boot-control-tomcat-cache)

but how to determine the exact required cache ?

- is it possible to listen to cache-exhausted events to react by increasing the cache
- Should we just look a the size of the `src/main/resources` or `../static` folder ?