# How to fix java.lang.NullPointerException in Http11InputBuffer.java?

Tags: java, apache, caching, nullpointerexception

I do Know What a NullPointerException means But in my case I'm receiving the exception from Http11Processor.java, Http11InputBuffer.java which I have never accessed it.

Complete Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:389)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

And a huge amount of warning Saying:

> WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
>   Jan 25, 2017 4:46:11 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
>
> INFO: The background cache eviction process was unable to free [10] percent of the cache for Context [/Duck] - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache. After eviction approximately [10,212] KB of data remained in the cache.

And my web project is getting really slow and is getting really hard to load if in my browser.

I'm using Apache 9.x and java 8

All replies are much appreciated

Comment: Please read the question before marking it a duplicate or down voting. I've already mentioned that i do know what nullpointerexception is but i'm getting the exception from a file comes with apache by default.

Comment: Well indeed is not a nullpointer Exception. Is because you have low Cache memory Try this  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893297/tomcat-8-throwing-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource-unable-to) hope it helped

Comment: @gatusko Thanks that worked :)