# Tomcat 8 has warning about not able to free cache of background cache eviction process

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8

I'm developing an app on spring mvc and sometime i see this message in console:

> The background cache eviction process was unable to free [10] percent of the cache for Context [/myApp] - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache. After eviction approximately [9,501] KB of data remained in the cache.

Why and What should i do now?

Thanks all

Comment: Although  [Tomcat 8 throwing - org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893297/tomcat-8-throwing-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource-unable-to) quotes a different error message, the instructions over there about increasing cache size helped me resolve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 8 throwing - org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893297/tomcat-8-throwing-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource-unable-to)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This message is related to your tomcat server,

In your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` add block below before `</Context>`

`<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />`