# Weird deployement on Tomcat with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have been working on a Java (Java 8) web application in Eclipse, using maven for one year. I created this webapp and use Maven v 3.5 since the beginning of my project. I usually deploy my web application on a tomcat 8.5 server ('Run as => run on server').

I have always managed my dependencies with my pom.xml, preventing with doing weird things using hte build path configuration menu from Eclipse.

The issue started yesterday : I add a dependency from other java/maven project I have madeand installed simply before, and add this lines on my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tlnPdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>tlnPdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

As my eclipse does sometimes when I add a new dependancy from other project, I had an issue when deploying the webapp, some message (sorry but I can't remember it) about the pom.properties from my other project. In this case, and as I always did, I just have to close my webapp project, launch a `mvn eclipse:clean` from a command prompt and then reopen my project; and the issue disappear.

Eclipse doesn't show issue on the classes that import classes from the new dependancy included.

Also I have a listener on a class at the starting of my webapp, declared on my web.xml :

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.package.InitTomcat</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This listener is funcional and I have not modified it lastly.

But yesterday, a new issue appear; when I wanted to deploy my webapp on my server, I had a lot of warning like this : 
`org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource at [...] to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - consider increasing the maximum size of the cache`. And then, an error telling me that the InitTomcat class does not exist :
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.InitTomcat`

So, firstly I thought that the cache warning was causing the issue. I did what this [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893297/tomcat-8-throwing-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource-unable-to) explain, and the warnings disappeared; but not the error.

Outside from eclipse, in a command prompt, I try to compile my project and getting my `app.war` file using `mvn clean install`. The compilation did not show any error, and the war is correct. I deployed manually my war on tomcat and no issue appeared.

Thus, I look on the two deployed directory (one from eclipse, the other manually by my app.war) and I saw something curious on the tree of repository deployed :

On the good deployed webapp (from app.war), I have something like that:

```
 |*some directories and files
 |*META-INF
 |*WEB-INF
     |*classes
       |com (etc...)
     |*lib
     |web.xml
```

And in the deployed webapp from eclipse :

```
*some directories and files
*META-INF
*WEB-INF
    |*classes
       |*.settings (why the hell does this directory are here ?)
       |*bin
          |*.settings
          |*src
          |*target
              |*classes
                  |*com ect... (my .class files are here !!)
              |*generated-sources
              |*m2e-wtp
              |*maven-archiver
              |*maven-status
              |*myapp (this directory have the same content as the "good web app deployed")
              |*test-classes
              |*WebContent
          |*temp
          |*webContent
          |pom.xml
          |.project
       |*src
       |*target
       |*temp
       |*WebContent
              |*...
    |*lib
    |web.xml
```

The "good" webapp as a size of 275Mb, the other is 865Mb

I suspect that the issue occur when eclipse deploy my web-app and which explain that it could not find the InitTomcat class since it seems to be at the wrong place. But I have no idea why it decided to do this now.

I tries to delete the project from eclipse, cleaning eclipse, etc... but no result. I have tried with 3 different versions of tomcat : 8.5.14, 8.2.23 and 9.0.2, always with the same behaviour

As I was depressed, I download the last version of eclipse, and import my webapp project into it with maven; but it has the same result.

Finally, my question is simple : does anyone has an idea of what it is happening, and how to solve it ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I finally saw where my problem was: looking on properties > "deployment Assembly" of my project, the deploy pathes were weird. I dont know when did he change, nor why, but I did the following to reinitiate "cleanly" them:

1. Delete the project (but not the sources) in eclipse
2. Manually **delete .settings directory, .classpath and .project files**
3. Import as a maven project in eclipse

These do the tricks. The issue is that before, I had not deleted the properties files from eclipse and the bag configuration was reload when importing the project.