# java.util.jar.jarfile.init() method takes too long to execute

Tags: java, performance, visualvm, tomcat9, openjdk-11

***Story:*** I am resolving some performance issues on my Web Application
Application background: This Application is written in `Java`, with `Velocity Template Engine`, and front-end `javaScript` using Tomcat9 server.

***Problem:*** When i leave the application running, for 10-15 min, the application slows down, So i tried to do `VisualVM` profiling, and found some traces, that i want to share with you people.

[image]
***UPDATE*** 
I debug it more, and find the main reason of redundant calls to `Open` function in `RandomAccessFile`

and this is the call stackeTrace 
[image]

In StandardRoot.java we have one method, which looks for Resources

```
private WebResource getResource(String path, boolean validate,
        boolean useClassLoaderResources) {
    if (validate) {
        path = validate(path);
    }

    if (isCachingAllowed()) {
        return cache.getResource(path, useClassLoaderResources);
    } else {
        return getResourceInternal(path, useClassLoaderResources);
    }
}
```

and this function calls `getResourceInternal` which leads to load resources 
again and again, if it still available

I tried to find some Tomcat configurations too. and i did some changes regarding to that like

in context.xml

```
<Context>
<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheTtl="36000000" cacheMaxSize="51200"/>

.........
..........
</Context>
```

This helps me to increase the time to cache the objects like by default cacheTtl is 5 seconds, I increased this to 1 hour and `cachingAllowed`  true
and `cacheMaxSize` is set to 50mb

I was able to load and read these parameters in `StandardRoot.java` but my calls to read Library file is not decreased.

***So basic problem is*** When I leave my application running(Means running on Tomcat server but not using on web browser) for 10-15 min, the application slows down, and when I did profiling of Application, I found this

java.util.jar.JarFile.init() method took 46 seconds

***What solution i need:***  if someone faced this kind of issue, or know where now i can further look-into, that would be good, Now I am facing stuck

Thanks in advance :)

PS: I erased some file names. because they are private and need to be secured 
thanks for not asking what are these files :)

Comment: I see at least two problems here. 1) [Wrong profiler](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2016/02/why-most-sampling-java-profilers-are.html). JarFile constructor is unlikely to be a bottleneck, since it does almost nothing except calling `super`. I suggest an OS-level profiler like [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler). 2) Calling `EventCartridge.addEventHandler` on each request. It's definitely something wrong with a way you call it, since it causes expensive class loading.

Comment: @apangin this ticket ais same as my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143525/jar-getting-inflated-when-any-class-is-referred-for-first-time-hence-large-del please have a loook

Comment: @apangin, I update some more debug traces, please have a look, and see what you can help with :)

Comment: This is not the same as the linked question, as that question is about `getNextJarEntry` operations, not about the constructor as yours. Besides, you have an `if (isCachingAllowed())` statement and say that the `getResourceInternal` invocation is the culprit, despite it’s in the else clause, in other words, it indicates that `isCachingAllowed()` returns `false`, contrary to your posted configuration…