# Changing Tomcat config - context.xml through dockerfile

Tags: docker, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have developed a web app (maven, tomcat) in Intellij and managed to create a container through '**Services**' tab in Intellij which was straightforward thanks to easy deployment config. During the process, I encountered that the **cache size was not enough** so I manually changed the **context.xml** (**added `<Resources cacheMaxSize="51200" />`**) file of tomcat manually locally after which the app ran smoothly.

To summarize the container creation in Intellij under services tab (see the bottom for the image):

```
 - pulling an image: tomcat:9.0.65-jre8
 - container name
 - bind ports: 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
 - bind mounts: mount host path which contains the war WITH /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Though not sure, I guess the war file I created took already into account the change I made in the **context.xml** file since my application server is the tomcat I downloaded and made the change on its context.xml.

However, I also need to create a container with a dockerfile:

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-jdk-8 as maven_builder
COPY . /usr/src/maven_pdfparse
WORKDIR /usr/src/maven_pdfparse
RUN mvn clean install -f /usr/src/maven_pdfparse && mkdir /usr/src/wars/
RUN find /usr/src/maven_pdfparse/ -iname '*.war' -exec cp {} /usr/src/wars/ \;
ADD pom.xml .

FROM tomcat:9.0.65-jre8
COPY --from=maven_builder /usr/src/wars/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

When I ran this on docker, I again got the '**insufficient cache**' issue.

So how can I make the same change on context.xml when creating a dockerfile?

Or is there a way to get the dockerfile automatically when I create the container through deployment configuration?

[image]

Comment: As part of your ``Dockerfile`` you can run a ``sed`` command (for example) to inject the required extra line into the ``context.xml`` file so that it is present when tomcat is started as the container starts up. Or perhaps you just need to set the ``cacheMaxSize`` in the ``context.xml`` of the packaged WAR itself?

Comment: Many thanks @JohnXF! I did not know sed command. When I added the line RUN sed -i 's#</Context>#<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />\n&#' ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/context.xml, it worked! If you want, give your answer below instead of a comment so I accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options to choose from if you wish to add to or modify the `context.xml` file.

1. You can modify the `context.xml` file already within the image as part of the image build. Add a `RUN` command using a command line tool like `sed` to add the required `<Resources>` element to the file.
2. You could also have a pre-modified version of the file and just copy it into the image to overwrite the existing one.
3. You could add a custom startup command that modifies the `context.xml` (e.g. using `sed` as per option 1) before invoking the usual tomcat startup script. Using this mechanism you could also get the `cacheMaxSize` value to use from an environment variable and thus allow run-time control of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying the Tomcat context *at build time* an interesting option could be to expose some parameters for modification *at runtime*.

```xml
 <Resources cacheMaxSize="${CACHE_SIZE:-51200}" />
```

Exposing these parameter for the runtime would allow you not to have to rebuild and deploy an image every time you need to fine tune a setting.

Those settings can be then defined via the environment variables passed to the container image at startup.

```bash
# docker run --env CACHE_SIZE=8192 localhost/my-tomcat
```

Variable which will be accessible to the application running within the container, in your case Tomcat

Recent versions (since latest v7.0) of Tomcat can handle that quite.
See the properties replacement feature, described in the Tomcat documentation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/systemprops.html)

Two ways to enable this feature:

- either by passing `-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.digester. PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource`  system variable to the JVM.
- or by adding the property to the `catalina.properties` file:

  ```
  org.apache.tomcat.util.digester. PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer

[Tomcat 8 throwing - org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource Unable to add the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893297/tomcat-8-throwing-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource-unable-to)

Where you'll need to update `context.xml` and rebuild your image with copying `context.xml`